# Distinguish Qt itemChange signal on item when move and edit

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, signals-slots

I have QTreeView and QStandatdItemModel. I have slot that connected to itemChanged signal, where I work up with new item data. Then I activated drag and drop possibility and find out that on mowing item I also receive itemChanged signal. But signature is only *QStandardItem**, so I can't say what have happened - was item data changed or was it just moved, but I need to know that. How can distinguish was item changed or moved?

Comment: check other signals (documented in parent class) http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractitemmodel.html#signals there is lots of possibilities (data change, move row/column).

Comment: @MarekR thanks! didn't noticed that myself.. Will you add your comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy of comment:
check [other signals](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractitemmodel.html#signals) (documented in parent class)  there is lots of possibilities (data change, move row/column).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`dataChanged`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal instead.

```
This signal is emitted whenever the data in an existing item changes.
```